# How to find last month's records from timestamp from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In my database table timestamp column datatype is longtext like this 1486335600.

How to write a mysql select statement to retrieve last month information?

```
SELECT `timestamp` FROM `daily_deals`
```

Comment: You should use a mysql date type to store that information, that will make this and future queries a lot easier.

Comment: but its something already they have done.i am not allowed to change data type at this moment

Comment: @shane can you use my ans your you need something change ?

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp are saved as unix timestamp, you can convert it to the date/time format with FROM_UNIXTIME():

```
select from_unixtime( 1486335600 )
```

last month information will be something like this:

```
select `timestamp`
from `daily_deals`
where
  `timestamp` >= unix_timestamp( current_date - interval 1 month )
```

but it depends on your requirements (e.g. you might want the whole January data now that we are in February, if that's the case we need to work a little on the where condition)

Comment: yes i want to get the whole January data i tried like this but it gave me an error select `timestamp`
from `daily_deals`
where
  `timestamp` >= '1486335600' ( current_date - interval 1 month );

Comment: @shane can you try with `where timestamp >= unix_timestamp( current_date - interval 1 month )` ?

Comment: ok it did work though,but how to extract last month from this 1486335600

Answer (score 1):

**from_unixtim()**  this function convert your value in date foment like **2017-02-06 05:30:00** so you can simply can you date in where condition

```
     SELECT `timestamp` FROM `daily_deals` where  
FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) BETWEEN 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-31
```

**using this you can get data between any two date**

Comment: SELECT `timestamp` FROM `daily_deals` where FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) BETWEEN 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-31 this returns me empty result set

Comment: select  FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) from `daily_deals` limit 0,2      run this query and tell me what is the result

Answer (score 0):

You should try below query to retrieve last month information.

```
SELECT `timestamp` FROM `daily_deals` WHERE date_created BETWEEN (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: for this solution, date_created has to exist (not sure), and must not be a string (as OP says...)

Comment: it gave me some errors 3 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "CURRENT_DATE" at position 112)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 124)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 125)

Comment: Make sure you have added date_created field in your database table.